# Статическое перемещение только влево и вправо + упирания в стену (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Получается, что свойства/методы вроде transform.position или Translate крайне не правильны по скольку они выталкивают объект, юзая же методы вроде addforce, velocity воздействуют на объект, где при перемещении, он скользит, что понятно. Есть ли какой-то вариант, чтобы сделать статический объект при перемещении, а так же упирался бы в стены?

Comment: `transform.position` или `Translate` крайне правильны. Они делаю то, что от них ждут. Вы же ожидаете чудес. Почитайте про коллизии (collision). Про VolumeBox, ограничивающий объект.

Comment: Ну так Transform и физический движок - разные штуки.

Comment: Я знаю, что трансформ это считай телепорт, а твердое тело это уже физические свойства в пространстве, однако мне хотелось сделать то, что я указывал ранее

Comment: Понимаю о чем ты. Сам сталкивался с такой проблемой. Как по мне, то проще будет юзать физику.